# What are the basic differences and similarities between Angular js and Express js?

Tags: node.js, angularjs

So I am a bit confused in regards to the aim of Angular js vs Express js. From my understanding we use Node.js to serve Angular js but we are not entirely limited/forced to use Node.js for serving it. Express js on the other hand seems like it accomplishes something similar to the more traditional MVC framework.

So is Angular Js a type of non-server-specific MVC framework? and does this limits Angular js backend server capabilities or ease of use?

Comment: Google brings me here, I do personally think that this is a pretty good question.  THanks @Prussian for asking it.

Comment: There are a number of questions like this, which are not programming questions per se, but that are very useful to provide context about a technology. Should there be a category for this type of question instead of just flagging it as "too broad?" It's not too broad. Agreed it's just not a coding question, but with all of the answers and Google traffic it gets, surely it has value and should be on SO.

Comment: Thnx guys. I think we often have moderators that are a bit overzealous. It is not related to a specific bug but it may be considered a coding question by many. In my case I was trying to elucidate some fundamental concepts before embarking in a project. Coding and development involve many steps. Not all questions will be equally "specific" and there should be an acceptable range. We could even say some "tags" are too broad. Whatever the decision is, all these factors should be acknowledged.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Express**

Express is a web framework, inspired by the Ruby project 'Sinatra'. It's one of many web frameworks in Node

**AngularJs**

AngularJS is a MVC framework that defines numerous concepts to properly organize your web application. Your application is defined with modules that can depend from one to the others. It enhances HTML by attaching directives to your pages with new attributes or tags and expressions in order to define very powerful templates directly in your HTML. It also encapsulates the behavior of your application in controllers which are instanciated thanks to dependency injection.

AngularJS helps you structure and test your Javascript code very easily.

Answer to your comment which i saw.

> So would you say they are for different purposes client-side vs
>   server-side implementations and therefore mutually exclusive or do you
>   see a scenario in which one could use Angular Js, Expression js, and
>   Node.js in the same application?

Yes, they are for different purpose, but they both are MVC based framework. Yes, we can where you can use Angular router, views and controller for front end and use express as your base model to communicate with MongoDB or anyother Database. But yet again its your choice, as you can achieve everything without even bothering AnagularJs.

**Adding more**.

AngularJS is a beautiful client-side framework, highly testable, that combines tons of cool stuff such as MVC, dependency injection, data binding and much more. If you want to fully take advantage of the AngularJS features you may consider coding the server side using a RESTful approach. you can take advantage of their resource factory, which creates an abstraction of your server side RESTful API and makes server-side calls such as get, post, put, delete etc.

You can use AngularJS for defining your client-side behavior[Views and Controllers] and then write up the REST-Services which AngularJS client can interact with. The client runs on the web browser[**AngularJS**], and does asynchronous communication to the server. The server[**ExpressJS**] then retrieves and stores data for the client.

**Maintaining a clear distinction between client and server makes the app easier to maintain and test.** Adding to it, it all depends upon what you are trying to build and how best you can leverage both of them.

Comment: So you wouldn't advice necessarily combining both? Why would someone want to do server side communication with Angular JS when they can achieve the same thing with Express? Moreover, it seems like Express is better because not all of your code would be exposed as in Angular JS. What are the advantages if any of using Angular JS?

Answer (score 11):

AngularJS is a javascript framework that runs on the client side, on the browser; it has a router, yes, but is only for the client side (in fact, it uses the hash as default).

On the other hand, Node.js runs javascript without a browser, as a service and it can run frameworks like Express, dealing with HTTP and so on, making it a nice web server.

Comment: So would you say they are for different purposes client-side vs server-side implementations and therefore mutually exclusive or do you see a scenario in which one could use Angular Js, Expression js, and Node.js in the same application?

Comment: Actually I use to develop the client side with Angular and the server side with Node and Socket.io. But also, I use Node to ease my workflow working with assets, minifying, testing... Take a look at Grunt.js, Yeoman... is a whole new world of possibilities based on javascript.

Comment: nodejs is not a web-sever. NodeJs is simply a library written for V8 which does evented I/O. You can write a web-sever on the top of NodeJs. Node is similar in design to and influenced by systems like Ruby's Event Machine or Python's Twisted

Answer (score 8):

Similarity is both are JavaScript frameworks which means you can write your server side and client side logic both in JavaScript if you were using them together.

Differences would be AngularJS is a client-side framework and Express is server-side framework.

Express can be used with any client-side framework and so can Angular be used with any server-side framework.