# Similarities and differences of Node.js and Angular.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am new to MVC (**Model View Controller**) and knows intermediate OOP in javascript.

Do **Node.js** and **Angular.js** has the same purpose?

Example, i wanted to create an attendance monitoring system. **Where** is the part that ill use **angular.js** and when to use **node.js**?

Comment: at the end of the day.. i think my question HELP the other newbies to the concept closed or not ^^

Comment: make life simpler. it's not an ugly questin after all

Comment: @extraRice The question was not closed because it was unhelpful or it was ugly. It was closed because you asked "how to use node/angular and which one to pick"- which can have many answers. It would be difficult to pick an acceptable answer. Also you compared two completely unrelated things making people think you have not done enough homework/research on the topic. They work at different platforms, which is a must-know for a web-developer. You can add to question what you have tried, so that it can be answered precisely.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817630/what-are-the-basic-differences-and-similarities-between-angular-js-and-express-j